# Cast first 16 bytes of allocated memory into a UDT

Tags: c++

```
class Object{
  // some code here
}

char* c = new char[64];
```

From what I understand from the code sample above, I have allocated 64 bytes of memory in the heap. So now I have a block of memory to work with.

My question: is it possible to cast just the first 16 bytes into an Object* of the above allocated 64 bytes? If yes, how do I do it? If no, why?

Comment: Maybe lookup _placement new_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think placement new is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot 'cast' the memory to type `Object`. It would violate strict aliasing rule at the bare minimum, and potentially (depending of `Object`) violate it start of lifetime as well, and lead to undefined behavior.

Instead, you want to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to properly construct the object in the allocated space. The code will look like this:

```
class Object{
  // some code here
}

char* c = new char[64];
static_assert(sizeof(Object) <= 64, "Can't use allocated storage");
Object* p = new (c) Object(/* args */);
```

Comment: It always violates the start of lifetime, even for simple `int`. It never violates strict aliasing.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Will accept the answer in 6 mins.

Comment: Also, you need to assert proper alignment.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it always violates strict aliasing rule, once you start accesing the object through the pointer. Alignment would only be a problem if `Object` alignment requirements are exceeding= __ STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ and there is no indication this is the case.

Comment: @BaummitAugen what do you mean by proper alignment?

Comment: @user3702643 there is no indication that you should be worried about alignment.

Comment: @SergeyA There are no two pointers of unrelated types storing or loading the same memory location. Note that pointers to `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` and `std::byte` are exempt from that rule. So there is no strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You misunderstand the rule. `char*` is exempted, but `Object*` is not. While it is always legal to access any pointer through `char*`, the opposite is not true, and you cannot access `char*` through any pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA Again, strict aliasing only forbids access though two pointers of unrelated type. Accessing the memory allocated in `new char[]` via `Object*` does not violate strict aliasing because no such two pointers are involved. The issue is purely related to lifetime.

Comment: I was wrong about the alignment, though. cc @user3702643

Comment: @BaummitAugen no, again, you are wrong. There is accessing through a pointer to `Object` to the address where dynamic type of the object is not `Object` (it is a char). You might want to re-read corresponding section of the standard.

Comment: Hm yeah, looks like I somehow got that mixed up. Sorry. Though the "potentially" with regard to the lifetime issue is still wrong. (Unless I messed that up, too, but [intro.object]/1 seems clear about that at least.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen lifetime might be a mistake on my side :) I would need to research it more.